# How and where should domain object methods be consumed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a model for an ASP.NET MVC app with DI and an ORM.

Lately, I've been looking into the pros and cons of writing all my business logic in a service layer vs placing logic specific to an entity in the entity class itself.  Methods declared in the entity classes are obviously called on a specific instance of the entity and can therefore only be called when that instance has been instantiated from a query to the ORM.

Let's say I have a `Product` entity and I declare an `ApplyDiscount` method on it.  Given an `ID` of a product passed in from a controller's action method, I must first query for an instance of the product using this `ID` and then call the `ApplyDiscount` method.  But where should the querying code take place? Is it a valid practice to declare a method in my service layer which takes an `ID`, queries for the `Product` instance, and then calls `ApplyDiscount` on that instance? Or should that code go somewhere else?

Ultimately, I'd like to know if having querying code in the service layer and having modification- code of the resulting entities in the entity classes themselves is the common / correct implementation when attempting to avoid a fat service layer & anemic domain model.

Does having the querying code in the service layer defeat the purpose altogether?

Comment: It would be nice if someone could provide references that discusses this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't defeat the purpose, but you're ending up migrating functionality (specifically, validation) into the service layer where it shouldn't necessarily be.

Generally, you'd want for the validation to occur at the earliest possible point; that is, if you've been given an invalid ID, you want to make sure that you've caught that invalid condition before starting an execution chain all through your logic.  Typically, this means performing the query in the controller and passing the resultant object through your service layer; this isolates the functionality of querying up to a high level in your execution chain, and prevents you from having to implement high-level exclusion logic in your service layer (for example, if an entire set of IDs is invalidated, you can perform that validation outside of your service layer, thereby isolating that associated logic and keeping you from needing to do that inside your service layer.

In general, consider the approach to be this: perform object-level validation and deserialization at the earliest point of reference, to migrate your logic as far up out of your service layer as possible, and thereby "thin up" your service layer.  There's a certain amount of flexibility involved here, of course, but as a general rule, it's a good one.

Comment: "This means performing the query in the controller and passing the resultant object through your service layer." So the service layer method would simply take the Product as a parameter and call `ApplyDiscount` to it?  Well a single line myproduct.ApplyDiscount() service layer method is certainly thin.  The controller would need references to various repositories to query and perform the validation though.

Comment: @Sanjeev: yes, assuming that's all your service layer does, it's certainly thin.  This really starts becoming valuable as an approach when your service layer begins accruing logic (as it almost certainly will over time); whatever logic you can avoid having in your service layer will make it simpler.  As a side note, is ApplyDiscount not a function of your service layer?  Have you considered whether or not it should be?

Comment: Well ApplyDiscount is just an example, but while on the topic, I could certainly use guidelines as to what kind of functionality dictates where these methods should be placed.  ApplyDiscount doesn't affect any other entities, so I had initially assumed that it belonged as a Product method.

Comment: @Sanjeev:  What's the rationale for not making Discount be an entity with a reference to a product, with just an Apply method?  I'm not saying that's the way it should be done, but it seems like that might be a different but valid way of looking at things that might bring some clarity.  Different perspectives, and whatnot.

Comment: I think you need to look at the domain closer. Are you applying a discount to a `product` (like a sale price for all customers), or is this a discount for an `invoice line item`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the need for a service layer here. If logic only affects one entity, I would put the logic inside the entity itself. (Obviously you shouldn't trust the user's input, I'm just showing this as hypothetical code.)

```
public ViewResult ApplyDiscount(int productId, decimal percent)
{
    var product = Database.Get<Product>(productId);
    product.ApplyDiscount(percent);
    Database.Save(product);
    return View(product);
}
```

Product:

```
public void ApplyDiscount(decimal percent)
{
    this.Price = this.Price * (1 - discount);
}
```

Comment: You mean `this.Price = this.Price * (1 - (percent/100));` right?  Anyway, it seems to be a matter of dispute as to whether the code you have placed in a controller's action method should be placed in a dedicated service layer method instead.  Which should be the priority: having minimal code in my service layer or minimal code in my controllers?  Thin controllers and a thin service layer are both important, from what I've learned.

Comment: @Sanjeev Well I'd actually choose a better name than `percent` since it's not clear what that means. I used to put everything in a service and have a very thin controller, but I realized I was just adding an unnecessary layer since I only use MVC for the UI. I still keep all my logic in the entities.

Answer (score -1):

Currently I'm using a static `Find` method on the entity, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult ApplyDiscount(int id, decimal percent) {

   Product product = Product.Find(id);

   if (product == null)
      return HttpNotFound();

   var result = product.ApplyDiscount(percent);

   if (result.IsError)
      return ViewWithErrors(result);

   return RedirectToAction("DiscountApplied");
}
```

`ApplyDiscount` returns an object with validation errors, which can be mapped to ModelState errors.